# How to keep alive Server sent event connection?

Tags: python, reactjs, server-sent-events, quart

I have a backend (Quart) API as a event source which is handling a time consuming operation. The time-consuming task takes around 2 min of time to generate some response.

To keep alive the connection I am sending heartbeat every 10 sec. I can see all this things working and my react frontend received the events correctly.

But, the problem is after every 1 min the api req gets canceled and create another request to the same endpoint.

What I want is that, keep on sending the heartbeat to the client till the time consuming task gets completed(after 2 min).

Here is my backend logic look like in python (quart):

```
import asyncio
from quart import Quart, Response, websocket

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.after_request
async def add_cors_headers(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
    return response

async def time_consuming_task(queue):
    # Simulate a time-consuming task
    await asyncio.sleep(120)
    # Once the task is completed, put the result in the queue
    await queue.put("Task completed")

async def in_progress_events(queue):
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield f"data: {i}\n\n"
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

@app.route('/sse')
async def sse():
    # Create a queue to communicate with the time-consuming task
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # Start the time-consuming task
    asyncio.create_task(time_consuming_task(queue))

    async def event_stream():
        while True:
            async for event in in_progress_events(queue):
                yield event

                # Check if there's a result in the queue
                if not queue.empty():
                    result = await queue.get()
                    yield f"data: {result}\n\n"
                    yield "event: close\ndata: Connection closed\n\n"
                    return

            # Send a heartbeat event to keep the connection alive
            yield "event: heartbeat\ndata: \n\n"
            await asyncio.sleep(50)  # Send a heartbeat every 50 seconds

    response = Response(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
    response.headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Also, the frontend logic:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function SSEComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:5000/sse');

    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log("onmessage", event.data);
      setData(event.data);
    };

    eventSource.addEventListener('close', () => {
        console.log("onclose");
      eventSource.close();
    });

    eventSource.addEventListener('heartbeat', () => {
        // Handle heartbeat events
        console.log('Received heartbeat event');
      });

    eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        console.log("error", error);
    };

    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Server-Sent Events Data:</h2>
      <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SSEComponent;
```

[console log with multiple same api calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p4Ql.png)